# Linux sort -Help Wanted

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, csv

I'm stuck in a problem for few days. Here it is maybe u got bigger brains than me!

I got a bunch of CSV files and i want them concatenated into a single .csv file, numeric sorted. Ok, first encountered problem is with the ID (i want to sort unly by ID) name. 
eg

`sort -f *.csv > output.csv` This would work if i had standard ids like id001, id002, id010, id100 
but my ids are like id1, id2, id10, id100 and this make my sort job inaccurate.

Ok

`sort -t, -V *.csv > output.csv` - This works perfectly on my test machine (sort --version GNU coreutils 8.5.0) but my live machine from work got 5.3.0 sort version (and they didn't had implemented -V syntax on it) and i cannot update it!

I'm feel so noob and unlucky
If you have a better idea please bring it on.

my csv file looks like

```
cn41    AQ34070YTW  CDEAQ34070YTW   9C:B6:54:08:A3:C6   9C:B6:54:08:A3:C4        
cn42    AQ34070YTY  CDEAQ34070YTY   9C:B6:54:08:A4:22   9C:B6:54:08:A4:20        
cn43    AQ34070YV1  CDEAQ34070YV1   9C:B6:54:08:9F:0E   9C:B6:54:08:9F:0C        
cn44    AQ34070YV3  CDEAQ34070YV3   9C:B6:54:08:A3:7A   9C:B6:54:08:A3:78        
cn45    AQ34070YW7  CDEAQ34070YW7   9C:B6:54:08:25:22   9C:B6:54:08:25:20
```

This is actually copy / paste from a csv. So let's say, this is my first CSV. and the other one looks like

```
cn201   AQ34070YTW  CDEAQ34070YTW   9C:B6:54:08:A3:C6   9C:B6:54:08:A3:C4    
cn202   AQ34070YTY  CDEAQ34070YTY   9C:B6:54:08:A4:22   9C:B6:54:08:A4:20        
cn203   AQ34070YV1  CDEAQ34070YV1   9C:B6:54:08:9F:0E   9C:B6:54:08:9F:0C        
cn204   AQ34070YV3  CDEAQ34070YV3   9C:B6:54:08:A3:7A   9C:B6:54:08:A3:78        
cn205   AQ34070YW7  CDEAQ34070YW7   9C:B6:54:08:25:22   9C:B6:54:08:25:20
```

Looking forward reading you!

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-kX.Y` for column `X` starting on `Y` character, together with `-n` for numeric:

```
sort -t, -k2.3 -n *csv
```

Given your sample file, it produces:

```
$ sort -t, -k2.3 -n file
,id1,aaaaaa,bbbbbbbbbb,cccccccccccc,ddddddd
,id2,aaaaaa,bbbbbbbbbb,cccccccccccc,ddddddd
,id10,aaaaaa,bbbbbbbbbb,cccccccccccc,ddddddd
,id40,aaaaaa,bbbbbbbbbb,cccccccccccc,ddddddd
,id101,aaaaaa,bbbbbbbbbb,cccccccccccc,ddddddd
,id201,aaaaaaaaa,bbbbbbbbbb,ccccccccccc,ddddddd
```

---

### Update

For your given input, I would do:

```
$ cat *csv | sort -k1.3 -n
cn41    AQ34070YTW  CDEAQ34070YTW   9C:B6:54:08:A3:C6   9C:B6:54:08:A3:C4        
cn42    AQ34070YTY  CDEAQ34070YTY   9C:B6:54:08:A4:22   9C:B6:54:08:A4:20        
cn43    AQ34070YV1  CDEAQ34070YV1   9C:B6:54:08:9F:0E   9C:B6:54:08:9F:0C        
cn44    AQ34070YV3  CDEAQ34070YV3   9C:B6:54:08:A3:7A   9C:B6:54:08:A3:78        
cn45    AQ34070YW7  CDEAQ34070YW7   9C:B6:54:08:25:22   9C:B6:54:08:25:20
cn201   AQ34070YTW  CDEAQ34070YTW   9C:B6:54:08:A3:C6   9C:B6:54:08:A3:C4    
cn202   AQ34070YTY  CDEAQ34070YTY   9C:B6:54:08:A4:22   9C:B6:54:08:A4:20        
cn203   AQ34070YV1  CDEAQ34070YV1   9C:B6:54:08:9F:0E   9C:B6:54:08:9F:0C        
cn204   AQ34070YV3  CDEAQ34070YV3   9C:B6:54:08:A3:7A   9C:B6:54:08:A3:78        
cn205   AQ34070YW7  CDEAQ34070YW7   9C:B6:54:08:25:22   9C:B6:54:08:25:20
```

Comment: Thank you but seems that i still got the same output >> id201, id202,id203, id40,id41,id42. I can give you the real files to check

Comment: Make sure your sample input matches the pattern. I am using comma as delimiter (`-t,`) and second column starting for 3th field as column (`-k2.3`). Consider adjusting it to your particular case.

Comment: I see... Can you check my updated answer? For this case, doing `sort -k1.3 -n` suffices.

Comment: it does after i rechecked my cvs files ... i had few lines different format on them  that's why the sort was not working.... sorry ... i have over 500 csv files like that ... was a crushing job.. THANK YOU EVERYONE

Answer (score 1):

If your CSV format is fixed, you can use the shell equivalent of the decorate-sort-undecorate pattern:

```
cat *.csv | sed 's/^,id//' | sort -n | sed 's/^/,id/' >output.csv
```

The `-n` option is present even in ancient version of `sort`.

**UPDATE**: the updated input contains a number with a different prefix, and at a different position in the line. Here is a version that handles both kinds of input, as well as other inputs that have a number somewhere in the line, sorting by the first number:

```
cat *.csv | sed 's/^\([^0-9]*\)\([0-9][0-9]*\)/\2 \1\2/' \
          | sort -n \
          | sed 's/^[^ ]* //' > output.csv
```

Comment: Thank you but this is not sorting my things out. The output is something like id201, id202,id203, id40,id41,id42

Comment: @Adrian You edited the question to change the test input, which broke the code in my answer.

Comment: @Adrian Updated the answer to reflect the new input.

Comment: i'm away of computer .. i will be able to check in 1 hour. Thank you big time!

Comment: I think that it is a bit overworking to replace all the leading `cn` while `sort` has the option to sort based on col and from a specific character.

Comment: @fedorqui For this particular use case I agree with you, but your answer wasn't yet available when I was writing this one. I didn't delete it because one can think of it as a different and more general approach, one that can cover cases that `-k` can't.

Comment: @Adrian I tried it with your test data, and it worked for me. I also don't see how you could get the output like `id201`... with the new version of my code — it looks as if you ran the old version.

Comment: Yes, I agree that in some cases it would cover cases in which `sort` is not useful. For example when the leading text is not fixed and you can define a regex with your `sed`.

Comment: @fedorqui Note that the current code doesn't handle that because it's more of an "undecorate-sort-redecorate". But with minor modification, this case would be covered by implementing a real decorate-sort-undecorate, and **prepend** the sort key to the line line, instead of removing the beginning. The final step would remove the prepended data.

Comment: @fedorqui The updated version of the code handles numbers at arbitrary positions in the line. sed's regular expressions syntax doesn't make this very elegant, but it still demonstrates the concept.

Comment: Interesting, good one! I just saw that `sort` has `-b` to "ignore leading blanks". Also, I thought that maybe you can also use for example `awk '{printf "%120s\n", $0}' file | sort -k1.50`. This way, `awk` will align text to the right and then you will be able to sort based on exact position.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `-g` option:
`sort -t, -k 2.3 -g fileName`

-t seperator
-k key/column
-g general numeric sort